# CSS box-shadow: can someone explain me the short syntax used in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, box-shadow

The Bootstrap framework uses a short syntax to define a `box-shadow` for `div.form-control:focus`:

```
.form-control {
    border-color: #3c763d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #2b542c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
}
```

What does the part befor the comma sets? The part after the comma defines the appearance of the shadow, but the part before? Where can I find more info about this?

Searching for this on Google I found [a page on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) but it seems explain only the part after the comma while I'm don't understanding the part before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using two different box shadows in one statement. The other is an inset border, which is inside instead of outside the element.

Take a look at [this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/) for more info about box shadows

Comment: Are you referring to the paragraph "Multiple borders and more" in the article you suggested?

Comment: the whole article is good but yes, you can see how they use multiple borders